# Is there any script in autohotkey to download reports from quickbooks

Tags: autohotkey, quickbooks

I need to download the reports sales report from intuit quickbooks using autohotkey script. I am new to both autohotkey and quickbook. The script need to automatically click through the report menu and select a report type and the date given through the input should be used as from and todate and after that the report should be exported to csv

Comment: Welcome to SO. We generally don't write code for you but will gladly help with problems in your program. We generally expect research effort. The AHK forums are a betters place to ask for help like this.

Answer (score -1):

I can't exactly tell how Quickbooks works, but after looking at their website, I'm sure you can loop over:

- Using `Click` to move around the report menu
- Executing `GuiControlGet, Name` to get the ClassNN of each report type or date
- Apply `ControlGetText` to retrieve the text/data of each report
- Utilize `FileAppend` to push all the data into a .csv